# R- How can I update column values only pertaining to rows where column contains beginning of a certain number?

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
ex <- data.frame("id" =c(rep(1234,6)),
                 "case" = c(45,45,45,92,92,93),
                          "cpt" = c(20600,25263,8456,2345,9023,"C1245"),
                         "date"=c("2019-05-21", "2019-08-22","2019-04-12",
                                  "2019-03-01", "2019-02-18", "2019-03-12"),
                         "window"=c(10,20,NA,45,NA,NA),
                         "pay"=c(520,140,2200,230,600,700))
```

I essentially have two questions:
How can I update the cpt column with the cpt value corresponding to the row with the highest *pay* grouped by case **only** focusing on any row containing a cpt value beginning with number 2 AND following this, how I can update the window column to replace any value that isn't the maximum with NA (also only focusing on rows where cpt value starts with 2)

I would like the final output to look like so:

```
ex1 <- data.frame("id" =c(rep(1234,6)),
                 "case" = c(45,45,45,92,92,93),
                 "cpt" = c(20600,20600,20600,2345,2345,"C1245"),
                 "date"=c("2019-05-21", "2019-08-22","2019-04-12",
                          "2019-03-01", "2019-02-18", "2019-03-12"),
                 "window"=c(10,NA,NA,45,NA,NA),
                 "pay"=c(520,140,2200,230,600,700))
```

I have two codes

```
ex[, cpt:=cpt[which.max(pay)], by=case]

ex %>% group_by(case) %>% mutate(window=replace(window, (pay < max(pay)), NA)) %>%
  setDT()
```

but both of these codes apply to the overall max value and will produce

```
ex2 <- data.frame("id" =c(rep(1234,6)),
                  "case" = c(45,45,45,92,92,93),
                  "cpt" = c(8456,8456,8456,9023,9023,"C1245"),
                  "date"=c("2019-05-21", "2019-08-22","2019-04-12",
                           "2019-03-01", "2019-02-18", "2019-03-12"),
                  "window"=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  "pay"=c(520,140,2200,230,600,700))
```

Is there any way I could alter the codes I have to get the output I'm looking for? Or any other code that might be more efficient? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical vector (`i1)` based on the first character of 'cpt' (`substr` - as the OP is interested in those elements that start with "2"), grouped by 'id', 'case', `if` there are `any` 'i1', then use that to subset the 'pay' get the index of the 'max' element with `which.max` and use that to subset the subset of 'cpt' (`cpt[i1]`) or `else` return the original column 'cpt', then we `replace` the 'window' where the 'cpt' is not the same as the duplicate column 'cpt1' (original column) to `NA` and `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
ex %>% 
  mutate(cpt1 = cpt) %>%
  group_by(id, case) %>% 
  mutate(i1 = substr(cpt, 1, 1) ==  "2", 
     cpt = if(any(i1)) cpt[i1][which.max(pay[i1])] else cpt,
     window = replace(window, cpt != cpt1, NA),
           i1 = NULL, cpt1 = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#     id  case cpt   date       window   pay
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1234    45 20600 2019-05-21     10   520
#2  1234    45 20600 2019-08-22     NA   140
#3  1234    45 20600 2019-04-12     NA  2200
#4  1234    92 2345  2019-03-01     45   230
#5  1234    92 2345  2019-02-18     NA   600
#6  1234    93 C1245 2019-03-12     NA   700
```

Comment: thanks! This code makes the change based on max cpt value, and not max pay value. I've updated the example to include a case where one row might have a cpt value of 25263 and a pay of 140, while another row has a smaller cpt value of 20600 but a higher pay of 520. How can I adapt the code to replace the value 25263 with 20600, since the pay is lower than 520?

Comment: @vdu12345 Is `ex2` the expected output

Comment: @vdu12345 can you explain the window value of 20 as 2nd element when the input was NA

Comment: ex1 is the expected output. ex2 is what I'm getting with the current codes I have. Only cpt values starting with a '2' will have a window value. So for example for case 45, I would like to replace window 20 with NA since it does not correspond to the cpt value with max(pay)

Comment: @vdu12345 you can check the updated solution.  It is now matching